# protected destructor object allocation on heap vs stack

Tags: c++

If a destructor is protected, why allocating an object on stack not allowed, but allocating on a heap is allowed?

```
class Foo
{
  public:
  Foo()
  {
  }
  protected:
  ~Foo()
  {
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo* objOnHeap = new Foo(); // compiles fine
  Foo objOnStack; // complains that the destructor is protected
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you're not destroying it by `delete`, the dtor won't be called at all.

Comment: I did not call `delete` for the object on heap. For the object on stack it gets deleted when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Yes this is the difference; the dtor is called or not. (implicitly or explicitly doesn't matter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an object with automatic storage duration (the standard term for what you call "on the stack"), it is implicitly destroyed when the object goes out of scope. This requires a publicly accessible destructor. When you allocate an object dynamically with `new`, this does not happen. The dynamically allocated object is only destroyed if you do it explicitly (e.g. with `delete`). You aren't trying to do that, so you don't get an error. You would get an error if you did this:

```
delete objOnHeap;
```

Comment: Good explanation. Even this **std::unique_ptr<Foo> p(new Foo());** would complain, since it uses delete inside.